# powershell xml variable encoding

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm invoking web services to retrieve XML data. I save response to xml variable:

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest $newURL -Method Post -Headers @{SOAPAction=$newURL} -ContentType "text/xml" -Body $queryBody
```

Result of the web service is xml with UTF-8 encoding in the header section.

However when I access some elements i.e. like this:

```
$response.Envelope.Body.describeSObjectResponse.result.fields[4].picklistValues
```

I can see that some values are converted to ascii because some national characters are replaced with character "?".

Could you please advise how can I read these elements in UTF-8 encoding?

**EDIT 1.3.2014:** 
Seems like the problem is with the Invoke-WebRequest. If I redirect output with -outfile switch to file, the encoding in the file is correct. If I then load content of the xml file into xml variable encoding is still correct.

Any ideas, how I can achieve the same but without redirecting the output to the file; i.e. working directly inside powershell logic?

Comment: What font are you using in the PowerShell host? The default font in the regular console host (the same one command prompt uses), [Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(typeface)), doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: I'm executing script in Windows PowerShell ISE and font is: Lucida Console 9pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be running into a bug with this command.  If this [Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/807794/invoke-webrequest-ignores-content-encoding) looks what you're seeing, be sure to vote on it.